# Write multiple Excel files for each value of certain column Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
data = {'Col_A': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'Col_B': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I can create a dataframa a and write it to Excel as follows:

```
a = df[df.Col_B == 'a']
a
a.to_excel(excel_writer = 'F:\Desktop\output.xlsx', index = False)
```

I am looking for a way to write an Excel file, for each value of column B. In reality, there are hundreds of values for Col_B. Is there a way to loop through this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Regards,

M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need for each group separate excel file loop by `groupby` object:

```
for i, a in df.groupby('Col_B'):
    a.to_excel(f'F:\Desktop\output_{i}.xlsx', index = False)
```

If need for each group separate sheetname in one exel file use [`ExcelWriter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for i, a in df.groupby('Col_B'):
        a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, index = False)
```

Comment: One additional question: Is there a way to import a column with percentages as is. By that I mean 68% will be imported as 68% instead of 0.68. Is that possible?

Comment: @SQL_M - I think not easy, only if use converters in `read_excel`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
for i in df.Col_B.unique():
    df[df.Col_B.eq(i)].to_excel('F:\Desktop\output'+i+'.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative, plus 1.